# AddAttachment Method in Kentico

Tags: c#, attachment, kentico

We are using Kentico v9 and are importing blog posts from Wordpress into Kentico.  We are having a problem importing the attachments into the blog post.  Here's the code currently being used:

```
var attachmentNode = TreeNode.New(FILE_PAGE_TYPE);
attachmentNode.DocumentName = filename;
attachmentNode.DocumentCulture = postNode.DocumentCulture;
attachmentNode.Insert(postNode);
DocumentHelper.AddAttachment(attachmentNode, "ce4c5d10-c143-4ada-9d8a-7e7481b167ef", localFileLocation, postNode.TreeProvider);
attachmentNode.Update();
```

This does not produce any error, and there is a record in the database for the file.  However, the file itself is not in Kentico.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [answer I provided](http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/addattachment-method-in-kentico) in the Kentico DevNet.

```
        TreeNode newNode = TreeNode.New(PageType, tree);
        newNode.DocumentName = mediaFile.FileName;
        newNode.DocumentName = fileName.Trim();
        newNode.SetValue("FileDate", fileDate);
        DocumentHelper.InsertDocument(newNode, parentNode.NodeID);

        AttachmentInfo newAttachment = null;

        // Path to the file to be inserted. This example uses an explicitly defined file path. However, you can use an object of the HttpPostedFile type (uploaded via an upload control).
        string filePath = MediaLibraryPath + @"\" + mediaFile.FileName + mediaFile.FileExtension;

        // Insert the attachment and update the document with its GUID
        newAttachment = DocumentHelper.AddUnsortedAttachment(newNode, Guid.NewGuid(), filePath, tree, ImageHelper.AUTOSIZE, ImageHelper.AUTOSIZE, ImageHelper.AUTOSIZE);

        // attach the new attachment to the page/document
        newNode.SetValue("FileAttachment", newAttachment.AttachmentGUID);
        DocumentHelper.UpdateDocument(newNode);
        newNode.Publish();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this code does any operation/processing of an actual file - it just saves a reference to that file into a database. If you want to save it in particular location in your file system you have to implement appropriate functionality.
See some [examples](https://docs.kentico.com/display/API9/Attachments) of API working with attachments.